# Hover effect stays after touch in jQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, hover

I'm developiong application in phonegap with jQueryMobile for mobile devices only. In which I've search icon. I want to give hover effect on that icon when user touchs it.

I've achived this by css:

```
<a href="search.html" class="custom_header" >

    .custom_header:hover {
        background:url('../images/effect_glow.png') no-repeat center;
```

Now the problem is this hover effect stays after touch. I want behaviour like mousein and mouseout. In this case effect stays even that part is not touching.

How to remove hover effect after finger get off on it?

Comment: Provide us with some HTML. What icon, where, how? Create a short jsFiddle example.

Comment: I don't think mobiles support `hover`, try `focus` instead

Comment: How would you hover on a touch screen?!?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You maybe know this but **`:hover`** doesn’t exist on touch screen devices. So when you design a responsive website, you should carefully plan when and where to use :hover interactions.

While it is implemented on mobile devices it is extremely buggy, mostly on iOS devices. On the other end you cant use **`:focus`** because it can be used only on a elements that support focus so a tags and buttons are ruled out. Also **`:active`** is no go on mobile devices.

In this case we can use jQuery to remedy this problem.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/84Nug/

In this example I have used **`vmousedown`**,  **`vmouseup`** and **`vmousecancel`** events so I can test it on desktop / mobile devices alike. Just replace them with **`touchstart`**,  **`touchend`** and **`touchcancel`**.

**`touchcancel`** / **`vmousecancel`** is needed because sometimes button can stay in pressed state.

**Code:**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).on('touchstart','.custom_header' ,function(){
        $(".custom_header").css("background","url('http://www.cesarsway.com/sites/default/files/cesarsway-images/features/2012/March/Puppies-and-Exercise.jpg') no-repeat center");
    }).on('touchend', function(){
        $(".custom_header").css("background","red");
    }).on("touchcancel", function() {
        $(".custom_header").css("background","red");
     }); 
});
```