# Trigger click on one anchor when another is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When I click on the link, I would like the link to be also clicked. However, nothing happens with my code, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/q2w4jjyt/18/).

HTML:

```
<section class="space_between">
  <h3 class="center_rounded_ol">Man-to-man suggestions</h3>
    <ol class="rounded-list center_rounded_ol">
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:" id="foo" onClick="burn()">Name Surname</a>
      </li>

    </ol>
</section>

<nav class="nav-fillpath">
  <a class="next" onClick="load()">
    <span class="icon-wrap"></span>
    <h3><strong>Alexis</strong> Tsipras</h3>
  </a>      
</nav>
```

JavaScript:

```
function load() {
  $("#foo").tigger('click');
}
function burn() {
  $(this).css("color", "red");
}
```

Comment: You really ought to be using event handlers in your JS rather than in your HTML.

Comment: Here's how you'd do that: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/r544j29j/

Comment: @isherwood thanks for tutoring me. Can I ask why or is it too much? And just in case, here is an updated fiddle of yours that answers better my question: jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/r544j29j/3 // I now see you are a pilot, so what you say should be true!!!!! ;) ;)

Comment: The more you can keep your content and the presentation of it separated the better it is for maintainability, scalability, etc. Google "separation of concerns" for more philosophy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally prefer writing it this way: [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/8m1okyzo/)

```
$('.next').on('click', function() {
    $("#foo").trigger('click');
});
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
   $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

```js
$('.next').on('click', function() {
  $("#foo").trigger('click');
});
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

```css
nav a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
nav a.prev {
  left: 0;
}
nav a.next {
  right: 0;
}
nav a svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
/*--------------------*/

/* Fillpath (http://www.nizuka.fr/)*/

/*--------------------*/

.color-10 {
  background: #f3cf3f;
}
.nav-fillpath a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.nav-fillpath a::before,
.nav-fillpath a::after,
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::before,
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 3px;
  height: 50%;
  background: #566475;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::before,
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::after {
  z-index: 100;
  height: 0;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: height 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}
.nav-fillpath a::before,
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::before {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
.nav-fillpath a.next::before,
.nav-fillpath a.next .icon-wrap::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(135deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
.nav-fillpath a::after,
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::after {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.nav-fillpath a.next::after,
.nav-fillpath a.next .icon-wrap::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
.nav-fillpath h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
}
.nav-fillpath a.prev h3 {
  left: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
.nav-fillpath a.next h3 {
  right: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(50%);
}
.nav-fillpath a:hover .icon-wrap::before,
.nav-fillpath a:hover .icon-wrap::after {
  height: 50%;
}
.nav-fillpath a:hover::before,
.nav-fillpath a:hover .icon-wrap::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-125deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-125deg);
}
.nav-fillpath a.next:hover::before,
.nav-fillpath a.next:hover .icon-wrap::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(125deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(125deg);
}
.nav-fillpath a:hover::after,
.nav-fillpath a:hover .icon-wrap::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-55deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-55deg);
}
.nav-fillpath a.next:hover::after,
.nav-fillpath a.next:hover .icon-wrap::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(55deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(55deg);
}
.nav-fillpath a:hover h3 {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  .nav-slide a.prev,
  .nav-reveal a.prev,
  .nav-doubleflip a.prev,
  .nav-fillslide a.prev,
  .nav-growpop a.prev {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  }
  .nav-slide a.next,
  .nav-reveal a.next,
  .nav-doubleflip a.next,
  .nav-fillslide a.next,
  .nav-growpop a.next {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  }
  .nav-slide a,
  .nav-reveal a,
  .nav-doubleflip a,
  .nav-fillslide a {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    transform: scale(0.6);
  }
  .nav-growpop a {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.6);
    transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.6);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="space_between">
  <h3 class="center_rounded_ol">Man-to-man suggestions</h3>
  <ol class="rounded-list center_rounded_ol">
    <li>
      <a href="" id="foo">Name Surname</a>
    </li>

  </ol>
</section>

<nav class="nav-fillpath">
  <a class="next">
    <span class="icon-wrap"></span>
    <h3><strong>Alexis</strong> Tsipras</h3>
  </a>
</nav>
```

---

**Update:**
using this is better because this way you separate your javascript all in `.js` or `<script>` instead of having it scattered on DOM elements so keep the HTML "clean", something like the inline CSS vs external CSS. Beside doing it this way you can easily attach more than one event..

This post **[jQuery.click() vs onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick)** has more detailed answer.

Comment: Nice. It seems, from the comments in my question, that this approach is better and it's not just your personal opinion. Any idea about that?

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo in load() function:

```
function load() {
  $("#foo").trigger('click'); //'r' was missing
}
```

Please note that

```
$(this)
```

inside burn() function returns window instance, is that what you are expecting there?

In case you want to change color of a link that gets clicked here is a HTML code (notice event parameter added):

```
<a href="javascript:" id="foo" onclick="burn(this)">Name Surname</a>
```

and js:

```
function burn(element) {
  $(element).css("color", "red");
}
```

This solution with 'this' lets you reuse burn() function for more that one link, it doesn't bind you to #foo elemenent only.

Comment: Instead of `event.target`, I think just passing `this` as the parameter should work as well.